# Changing the value of the download attribute of an anchor with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, download, rename

I want to change the value of the `download` attribute with javascript, I'm trying to use the `download` atribute of a `<a>` tag. But I dont know how to include javascript inside `download`?

```
<a href="REALFILENAME.txt" download="JAVASCRIPT_FUNCTION_HERE">CLICK ME</a>

function getDownloadName(){
    return "REALFILENAME_" + new Date().getTime();+ ".txt";
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it by setting the download attribute using [setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.setAttribute) as follows:

```
function getDownloadName(){
    return "REALFILENAME_" + new Date().getTime();+ ".txt";
}

function setDownloadAttribute() {
    var a = document.getElementById("fileLink");
    a.setAttribute("download", getDownloadName())
}

var a = document.getElementById("fileLink");
a.onclick = setDownloadAttribute;
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/1o1n8Ln0/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Provided that I have understood your question correctly. you need to add a [`click`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onclick) event handler to you `anchor` elements ( [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener)). Then manipulate the `href` value of the `anchor` and set the [`download`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-download) attribute (HTML5 only). I don't believe you really want Javascript code contained in the `download` attribute?

```js
var out = document.getElementById('out');

// add a click event handler to all anchor elements on the page
[].forEach.call(document.getElementsByTagName('a'), function (element) {
    element.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        var download = e.target.href.split('.').join('_' + new Date().getTime() + '.');
      
        // the following line is what would be used, HTML5
        e.target.download = download;
      
        // the following lines are added to show you what is happening,
        // prevent the event downloading and output the download URL
        e.preventDefault();
        out.textContent += download + '\n';
    }, false);
});
```

```html
<a href="REALFILENAME.txt">CLICK ME</a>
<pre id="out"></pre>
```